relation "user" does not exist (during SQLAlchemy table creation)
I have this in my extensions/extensions.py:
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from datetime import datetime

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    openid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    oauth_provider: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)

    sessions: Mapped[list["Session"]] = relationship("Session", back_populates="user")
    tips: Mapped[list["Tip"]] = relationship("Tip", back_populates="user")

class Session(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "session"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    minutes: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, default=100)
    session_date: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp())

    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="sessions") 

class Tip(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tip"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    tip_title: Mapped[str]
    tip_content: Mapped[str]

    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="tips")

my app.py: (only db creation code included)
from extensions.extensions import db, bootstrap, login_manager, User, Session, Tip
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = uri or "sqlite:///fallback.db" # uri got from heroku env
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("\n\n\nThis is logging check\n\n\n")

    with app.app_context():
        inspector = inspect(db.engine)
        logging.info(f"\n\n\nExisting tables before create: {inspector.get_table_names()}\n\n\n")
        try:
            db.drop_all()
            logging.info("\n\n\nTables dropped successfully.\n\n\n")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"\n\n\nError dropping tables: {e}\n\n\n")
        except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"\n\n\nError dropping tables: {e}\n\n\n")
        
        try:
            db.create_all()
            logging.info("\n\n\nTables created successfully.\n\n\n")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"\n\n\nError creating tables: {e}\n\n\n")

        inspector = inspect(db.engine)
        logging.info(f"\n\n\nTables present after create_all: {inspector.get_table_names()}\n\n\n")

    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))  # Default to 5000 if PORT not set
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)

The logging check is not even showing up, and I couldn't figure out a way to check. In the error, it says:
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "user" does not exist

Please [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback.
